# wpf scrollview scroll on swipe

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer

i have a scrollviewer like this:

```
<DockPanel>
        <Button Height="30" Width="26" Margin="20" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Background="#FF7F90FC" BorderBrush="#95FFFFFF" OpacityMask="{DynamicResource Arrow22}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Button.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="180"/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Button.RenderTransform>
        </Button>
        <ScrollViewer  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="100" Width="1060" PanningMode="HorizontalOnly">
            <StackPanel x:Name="pvdItems" Orientation="Horizontal">

            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <Button Height="30" Width="26" Margin="20" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Background="#FF7F90FC" BorderBrush="#95FFFFFF" OpacityMask="{DynamicResource Arrow22}"/>


    </DockPanel>
```

how can make it to be able to scroll by swiping it, note that i have hidden all the scrollbar.

i wan something like this [deme video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lwm2O070jt4) but i cant find the source code

eventually, i also want to make it able to scroll by the button clicks

Comment: you may consider use transparent thumb.

Comment: Have you tried setting `PanningMode="Both"` for `ScrollViewer`